# Netbeans Ant sign 2 jars separately?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar, sign

I have a large netbeans java project (with multiple applets) that currently gets built into one jar through a netbeans built-in Ant script. I would like to obfuscate this jar and then sign both the original and the obfuscated version.  My question is, what do I make my target depend on?  If I do the following:

```
<target depends="jnlp" name="-post-jar" description="obfuscate jar.">
```

Then the target gets executed AFTER the initial jar has been signed. Evidently, this invalidates the signing process done to the first jar.  Does anyone know how to create a target that happens between the jar-build and jar-sign processes? Or should I just take the current signing process out of netbeans and write it myself in this new "-post-jar" target?

I've come across [this](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?t=37686)  But I don't know how to apply it without editing the built in ant scripts... Any help is appreciated.